# javax.ejb.EJBException when trying to inject form data into database

Tags: java, ejb, constraints, bean-validation, transactionmanager

I'm trying to inject data into database based on form input but when I submit the form, i'm facing a nasty exception and I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around a scalable solution and I have tried many... Maybe you can help? I'm not sure what the program is trying to tell me...

Im using:

- Netbeans 8*
- Glassfish 4*
- Java EE 7

The Warning:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ControllerServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ControllerServlet threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy306.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at session.__EJB31_Generated__OrderManager__Intf____Bean__.placeOrder(Unknown Source)
    at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:409)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
```

The Cause

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at session.OrderManager.addCustomer(OrderManager.java:55)
    at session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
```

If it is useful to you, please see below the lines in my code it is referring to:

at controller.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:409) refers to code:

```
int orderId = orderManager.placeOrder(FN, LN, EM, PN, A1, CTRY, SPR, PZC, CT, cart);
```

at session.OrderManager.addCustomer(OrderManager.java:55) refers to code:

```
em.persist(customer);
```

at session.OrderManager.placeOrder(OrderManager.java:34) refers to code:

```
Customer customer = addCustomer(FN, LN, EM, PN, A1, CTRY, SPR, PZC, CT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a constraint violated on your model that is detected before persisting to the datastore. This means that your Customer or related entities has a Validation (eg. @NotNull, @Size) that is not honored. I think the cause of the cause(a level lower on your stack trace)might give you more info on this violation.

Comment: Thank you brother! It's exactly what it was! I removed every @NotNull annotation from each class I was trying to inject in the database and it worked! :D